# Fargate logging issue using log4j2

Tags: log4j2, aws-fargate

We have a fargate service running. On CloudWatch we can see the metrics for ECS/ContainerInsights->StorageWriteBytes growing every hour, and at some point it will not increase anymore probably because out of disk space. We will start to see log errors if we do not force a new deployment of the ECS. The error looks like:

```
error: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error 
writing to RandomAccessFile /apollo/env/ReaverFeatureGating/var/output/logs/application.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}
```

Questions:

1. Is this normal to all the fargate services? Do we setup something
   wrong?
2. Can we remove all the AmazonRollingRandomAccessFile and just use STDOUT in log4j2-container.xml? Will that still post our events to
   CloudWatch, but just not writing to the disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research this is what I got:

1. Because the default template includes AmazonRollingRandomAccessFile, the log will be generated locally but never be cleaned up. There are some suggestions about adding a cron job to delete the logs, but for our case we don't need the local logs.
2. Yes, CloudWatch just need STDOUT.

Also, StorageWriteBytes only represent how many bytes are read/write to the storage. It is not equal to the used disk space. To monitor the disk space, we can build CloudWatch Agent into the container image and then use disk_used metric.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html